# Is There Any Way to Remap the Controls?

Tags: miner-wars-arena

I picked up *Miner Wars: Arena* a little while ago, and it's pretty entertaining (although depressingly limited).  The split screen multiplayer mode is a good competitive game to play with a friend, but the default keyboard controls for Player 2 are *terrible*.  Worse still, I can't find a way to customize the controls in the in-game menus.

Am I just missing it somewhere?  Or is there some other way I can remap the controls to my liking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but there's no way to change controls in Miner Wars Arena.

The good news is that player2 should be able to play without problems - we designed it that way. If you look into game help screen, you will see that there are multiple ways how to operate as player2.

Comment: This is unfortunate.  The other player didn't like any of the P2 controls, and frankly, neither did I.  It's playable I guess, but some customization would be nice.